# Is a rigid cycle a chordal graph?

Tags: graph-theory, rigid-transformation

There are two relevant questions:

(1) We know an edge set $C$ is a rigid cycle in $\mathcal{G}_2(n)$ if and only if $|E(C)|=2|V(C)|-2$ and $|F|\leq 2|V(F)|-3$ for every proper subset $F$ of $E(C)$. Thus, I want to know: Is a rigid cycle a chordal graph? (It can be found in Wiki that chordal graphs are also called as "rigid circuit graphs". But i can't find the connection between it and rigid cycle. Are they the same thing?)

(2) A graph $G=(V,E)$ is defined as pseudocycle iff $|E|=2|V|-2$ and $F\leq 2|V(F)|-2$, $\forall\ \emptyset\subset F\subset E$. Thus, I also would like to know: Is a pseudocycle a chordal graph?

Thanks very much!

Comment: What is $\mathcal{G}_2(n)$ ?

Comment: These definitions comes from the book Combinatorial Rigidity by Jack Graver, Brigitte Servatius and Herman Servatius. In their book, G2(n) is the unique maximal 2-dimensional abstract rigidity matroid on n vertices. It would be OK if just thinking the graph C satisfies the condition. And I just want to know whether such a $C$ is chordal or not. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, what I am most interested in the elimination order (not necessarily perfect) of certain graph (so-called pseudocycle) formed by the union of two spanning trees. The elimination order I mean is the order of vertices according to which I delete each vertex and add edges between the remaining vertices incident to the deleted vertex (if there is no edge between those incident vertices). The elimination order I want to find in the pseudocycle is the order that allowes me to add at most O(n) extra edges totally.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a graph $G$ by starting with a $C_4$ (cycle of length 4) on vertices $a,b,c,d$, then adding a fifth vertex $e$ adjactent to all other four vertices.

Notice that $G$ isn't chordal because of the $C_4$.

Now $|E(G)| = 8 = 2|V(G)| - 2$.
Also, take any $F \subset E(G)$.  If $|V(F)| = 5$, then clearly the inequality is satisfied.
Otherwise say $|V(F)| = 4$. 
Then either $V(F) = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and $|F| \leq 4 \leq 2|V(F)| - 3$, or $V(F)$ is $e$ and 3 other vertices and $|E(F)| \leq 5 \leq 2|V(F)| - 3$.  You can verify the case with $|V(F)| = 3$.